# How do I thread an Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

If I define

```
network[n_List]:=Thread[
    (<|"w"->Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]],#2, #1],
       "b"-> Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]],#2]|> &)[Most@n,Rest@n]];
```

and attempt, for example

```
network[{1,2,3}]
```

I get

> Table::itraw: Raw object 2 cannot be used as an iterator. >>

What's going on here? How can I thread the association over my arguments?

Comment: Would `MapThread` be more appropriate?  You would get a list of associations.  I can't tell if that's what you're after.

Comment: @MichaelE2: The desired result would be what I'd get from `Thread[l[Most@n,Rest@n]]/.l->(<|"w"-> Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]],#2,#1], "b"-> Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]],#2]|> &)`. How would I do that with `MapThread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
network[n_List] := 
  MapThread[
   (<|"w" -> Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], #2, #1], 
      "b" -> Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], #2]|> &),
   {Most@n, Rest@n}];

SeedRandom[0];
network[{1, 2, 3}]
(*
  {<|"w" -> {{-0.619487}, {-0.798718}},
     "b" -> {0.36195, -1.09919}|>,
   <|"w" -> {{-1.30657, 0.74753}, {-0.283601, 0.0598676}, {0.509336, -0.663203}}, 
     "b" -> {0.452192, -0.27623, -0.457804}|>}
*)
```

Comment: does it thread through association or throug `{Most@n, Rest@n}` part? :)

Comment: @garej It threads through `{Most@n, Rest@n}`, which is what happens in the OP's code in the response to my query in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

With `Thread`:

```
network[n_List] := Activate@Thread[Inactivate[
           <|"w" -> Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], #2, #1], 
             "b" -> Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], #2]|> &][Most@n, Rest@n]];

SeedRandom[0];
network[{1, 2, 3}]

(* {<|"w" -> {{-0.619487}, {-0.798718}}, 
      "b" -> {0.36195, -1.09919}|>, 
    <|"w" -> {{-1.30657, 0.74753}, {-0.283601, 0.0598676}, {0.509336, -0.663203}}, 
      "b" -> {0.452192, -0.27623, -0.457804}|>} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more readable `v, c` stand for `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]`

```
network[n_List] := 
  (<|"w" -> Table[v, #2, #1], "b" -> Table[c, #2]|> &) @@@ Partition[n, 2, 1];
```

> {<|"w" -> {{v}, {v}},                  "b" -> {c, c}|>,
>
> <|"w" -> {{v, v}, {v, v}, {v, v}},    "b" -> {c, c, c}|>}

Comment: The `Thread` is not necessary in this situation, as the evaluation within it is performed before it fires. This definition of `network` will return the same result if `Thread` is removed.

Comment: @Xavier, I was trying to be closer to OP and then decided to make an imprivement with Partition :))

Comment: I see :) The `@@@` and `Partition` is nice. +1

Comment: @Xavier, Thank you, +1 for your version as well, I did not know  about `Activate` construct.